# how should i link php to server and client wsdl after complied with gsoap

Tags: php, wsdl

at first i had two c++ server and client program, run two program on a local computer separately and input a name in client side, then server will recieve request and send back the phone number and display on the client side. after complie with gsoap, Here is what i got the wsdl file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="test"
 targetNamespace="test"
 xmlns:tns="test"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:test="test"
  xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
 xmlns:MIME="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
 xmlns:DIME="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/dime/wsdl/"
 xmlns:WSDL="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
 xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"> 
<types> 
 <schema targetNamespace="test"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:test="test"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
  <!-- operation request element -->
  <element name="getMobile">
   <complexType>
    <sequence>
     <element name="user" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/><!-- test__getMobile::user -->
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
  </element>
  <!-- operation response element -->
  <element name="getMobileResponse">
   <complexType>
    <sequence>
     <element name="phone-num" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/><!-- test__getMobile::phone_num -->
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   </element>
 </schema> 
</types> 
<message name="getMobileRequest">
 <part name="parameters" element="test:getMobile"/><!-- test__getMobile::test__getMobile -->
</message> 
<message name="getMobileResponse">
 <part name="parameters" element="test:getMobileResponse"/>
</message> 
  <portType name="testPortType">
 <operation name="getMobile">
  <documentation>Service definition of function test__getMobile</documentation>
  <input message="tns:getMobileRequest"/>
  <output message="tns:getMobileResponse"/>
  </operation>
  </portType> 
<binding name="test" type="tns:testPortType">
 <SOAP:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
 <operation name="getMobile">
  <SOAP:operation soapAction=""/>
   <input>
  <SOAP:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
 </input>
 <output>
    <SOAP:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
  </output>
</operation>
</binding> 
<service name="test">
 <documentation>gSOAP 2.8.3 generated service definition</documentation>
 <port name="test" binding="tns:test">
 <SOAP:address location="http://192.168.82.52:35088"/>
 </port>
 </service> 
 </definitions>
```

now should i create two separated php file in two folders one php file should be enough?ive check some code on the internet but still not quite sure where o step in...
thanks!

and for my c++ program function, if i want to hard code user input in php, should i do

```
 $result = $sc->getMobile("Grace");
```

or sould i put a array in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do here - are you trying to write the client side program? What have you got so far?

You can parse the xml string that is returned from the SOAP request using SimpleXMLElement:

```
$xmlobj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
```

Reference on SimpleXMLElement located here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php